# Using Xargs to write a tar archive in numerical order

Tags: tar, xargs

I need to write an LTO of single frame files (`DPX`) in frame number order.

When using the standard command below the frames are written out of order.

```
tar -b 1024 -cvf /dev/nst0 <directory>
```

When using the below command I get an argument list too long response

```
tar -b 1024 -cvf /dev/tape ls <directory>
```

Here is how the files are laid out (I am starting the archive from the directory above the below):

`DIRECTORY_NAME/FILE_NAME.00259200.dpx - 00289805.dpx`

Any advice would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

GNU `tar` can read a list of files to add to the archive from a file or stdin with the `-T` option. Assuming the files in question can be sorted lexicographically:

```
find <directory> -type f | sort | tar -T - -b 1024 -cvf /dev/tape
```

Comment: You could also pipe `ls` directly to `tar`, but you'd lose the leading directory name, and you'll need to tell `tar` to change (`-C`) to the directory so it can find the files. You could also post-process the output of `ls` with `sed` or similar to prepend the directory name, then pipe that to `tar`: `/bin/ls mydir/ | sed 's/^/mydir\//' | tar -T - -b 1024 -cvf /dev/tape`. Note that if you use `ls`, you'll want to avoid colors (ANSI escape codes) in the output, so use the full path or escape the command with a backslash.